# How to open file/folder in system file explorer?

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to open a file or folder in the left "Folders" bar in the system file explorer?  Without this I have to open file explorer and navigate all the way to wherever this folder is in order to manipulate files, which is really inconvenient.  This is a standard function for most tools with a navigation bar like this, I'd be very surprised if this was not possible in ST.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you right click on a file in the sidebar, you have the option to "Open Containing Folder...", which will open the folder in your OS' default file explorer application.

[image: sidebar open containing folder]

However, there doesn't, by default, seem to be an option when you right click on a folder in the sidebar. However, as it is ST, it is easily customizable:

Create a file called `Side Bar.sublime-menu` in your `User` folder under the folder that is opened when you go to the Tools menu -> Browse Packages. Paste in the following contents and save it:

```js
[
    { "caption": "Explore Folder…", "command": "explore_folder", "args": {"dirs": []} },
]
```

Then, Tools -> Developer -> New Plugin... and replace the contents of the buffer with the following:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ExploreFolderCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, dirs):
        for dir_path in dirs:
            self.window.run_command('open_dir', { 'dir': dir_path })

    def is_visible(self, dirs):
        return len(dirs) > 0
```

and save it in the same folder as `explorefolder.py`

Now you will see a new item in the context menu on folders:

[image: new explore folder sidebar context menu item]

Comment: Thanks Keith. I never knew I was missing this until now. One ever-so-trivial, non-breaking, quibble. `dir` is a reserved Python keyword so should ideally be changed to, for example, `dir_path` in the `run()` method's loop.

Comment: nice spot, I didn't think of that :) I've changed it to `folder` instead ;)

Comment: I changed my mind, I prefer your `dir_path` suggestion ;) more informative :)

Comment: Don't you just hate it when reserved names get in the way of what you want to call a variable; `dir` is my pet hate but `id`, `str`, and `sum` always cause minor annoyance too. :)